# Parsing the output of a subprocess while executing and clearing the memory (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I need to parse the output produced by an external program (third party, I have no control over it) which produces large amounts of data. Since the size of the output greatly exceeds the available memory, I would like to parse the output while the process is running
and remove from the memory the data that have already been processed.

So far I do something like this:

```
import subprocess

p_pre = subprocess.Popen("preprocessor",stdout = subprocess.PIPE) 
# preprocessor is an external bash script that produces the input for the third-party software
p_3party = subprocess.Popen("thirdparty",stdin = p_pre.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

(data_to_parse,can_be_thrown) = p_3party.communicate()

parsed_data = myparser(data_to_parse)
```

When "thirdparty" output is small enough, this approach works. But as stated in the Python documentation:

> The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

I think a better approach (that could actually make me save some time),
would be to start processing `data_to_parse` while it is being produces,
and when the parsing has been done correctly "clear" `data_to_parse` removing
the data that have already been parsed.

I have also tried to use a for cycle like:

```
parsed_data=[]
for i in p_3party.stdout:
    parsed_data.append(myparser(i))
```

but it gets stuck and can't understand why.

So I would like to know what it is the best approach to accomplish this? What are the issues to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subprocess.Popen() to create a steam from which you read lines.

```
import subprocess

stream = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

for line in stream:
    #parse lines as you recieve them.
    print line
```

You could pass the lines to your `myparser()` method, or append them to a list until you are ready to use them.. whatever.

---

In your case, using two sub-processes, it would work something like this:

```
import subprocess

def method(stream, retries=3):
    while retries > 0:
        line = stream.readline()
        if line:
            yield line
        else:
            retries -= 1

pre_stream = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
stream = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=pre_stream, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

for parsed in method(stream):
    # do what you want with the parsed data.
    parsed_data.append(parsed)
```

Comment: What's the difference from OP's attempt `for i in p_3party.stdout`?

Comment: @JanneKarila True, there is not much difference, mine uses an iterator. I will edit to add something truly fun.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a file as in `for i in p_3party.stdout:` uses a read-ahead buffer. The `readline()` method may be more reliable with a pipe -- AFAIK it reads character by character.

```
while True:
    line = p_3party.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    parsed_data.append(myparser(line))
```